# Is there a posibility to link 2 models in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a quiz web app, where you will enter the app and you will have 2 buttons:

- create a quiz
- solve a quiz

You can do it without needing to register. I've created the models, one for Quiz and one for Question and I've put an UUID primary key to the quiz so that I can use this unique id as an extension to my link to get to the quiz that contains the questions.

My problem is this. After I create a quiz, I want to stay in that instance and directly go to the create questions file regarding the created quiz. Because right now after I create the quiz, I need to separately go and create a question, then make a dropdown to select the quiz which the question is for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr4iP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5tFt.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GdcK.png

```
    Views.py:
    # QUIZ
    class QuizCreateView(CreateView):
        template_name = 'quiz/add_quiz.html'
        model = QuizIdentifier
        success_url = reverse_lazy('add-question')
        form_class = QuizIdentifierForm



    class QuizDetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = 'quiz/detail_quiz.html'
        model = QuizIdentifier


    # QUESTION
    class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
        template_name = 'quiz/add_question.html'
        model = Question
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        form_class = QuestionForm


    def get_questions_per_quiz(request, pk):
        get_questions_per_quiz = Question.objects.filter(quiz_id=pk)
        context = {'all_questions': get_questions_per_quiz, 'pk': pk}
        return render(request, 'quiz/quiz_questions.html', context)
```

```
    models.py
    class QuizIdentifier(models.Model):
        creator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
        editable=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.creator_name


    class Question(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        op1 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        op2 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        op3 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        op4 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        quiz = ForeignKey(QuizIdentifier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null='True')
  
        def __str__(self):
            return self.question
```

```
    forms.py
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question', 'op1', 'op2', 'op3', 'op4', 'answer']
        widgets = {
            'question': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the question!'}),
            'op1': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the first option!'}),
            'op2': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the second option!'}),
            'op3': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the third option!'}),
            'op4': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the fourth option!'}),
            'answer': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the answer!'}),
            'quiz': Select(),
        }

    def __init__(self, id_quiz, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quiz'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.filter(id=id_quiz))
        self.initial['quiz'] = Question.objects.get(id=id_quiz)
        self.fields['quiz'].widget = HiddenInput()


class QuizIdentifierForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizIdentifier
        fields = ['creator_name']
        widgets = {
            'creator_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your name!'})
        }
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeTemplateView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('add-question', views.QuestionCreateView.as_view(), name="add-question"),
    path('quiz/<str:pk>', views.get_questions_per_quiz, name='quiz'),
    path('create-a-quiz/', views.QuizCreateView.as_view(), name="create-a-quiz"),
    path('quiz-details/<str:pk>', views.QuizDetailView.as_view(), name='quiz-details'),

]
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Edit the question and paste the snippets directly in your question using the `code` tags.

Comment: @OulTimotei For adding code just copy and paste you code and format it using the CodeSample button in the menu bar of the editor. It is really easier to answer questions when the code can be copy and pasted by people trying to answer you question so they can try out things. Nobody really likes to copy code by typing it off.

Comment: @OulTimotei: Regarding your question: Have you looked a [inlineformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: I tried to post the code now, hope its ok . @Chris, im looking over inlineformsets now

Comment: @OulTimotei Yes, now your code is ok and people can easily work with it!

Comment: @Chris ok so i looked into inlineformsets , i am a begginner, that might work , but in my case , when i create a quiz, i dont need to click on it from somewhere else. imagine u are using the website i talked about , and if u want to create a quiz , when u press the create quiz button , it will make u enter your name , press next then u can create the questions for that quiz directly there. thats what im looking for . I might not understand how to use inlineformsets properly.

Comment: Could you post your urls.py?

Comment: @chris Sure , here

Comment: @Chris , i tought about the QuizCreateView reverse lazy to the QuizDetails , but i cant link them to the <str:pk> at the details link for some reason . i tought that after i create the quiz , it will redirect me to the details of that quiz that will have the UUID in the link , and from there i could add the questions. But i cant do it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the line of thought you posted in your comment looks correct.

In your QuizCreateView you could create the success_url dynamically:

```
class QuizCreateView(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('add-question', kwargs={'quiz_id': self.object.pk})
```

In your urls.py add the quiz_id to your url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeTemplateView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('add-question/<quiz_id>/', views.QuestionCreateView.as_view(), name="add-question"),
...
]
```

Now you have got the quiz_id in your QuestionCreateView and you can use ist by overriding the form_valid method:

```
class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
   ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        res = super().form_valid(form)
        self.object.quiz_id = self.kwargs['quiz_id']
        self.object.save()
        return res
```

Comment: Thank you it works! i had some errors but they were my miss spelling, thank you so much !